# Linking a LinkedList as an element to a different LinkedList

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I'm working on a C++ assignment where I'll create a search engine on a linked list of linked lists. As per the requirements, I can't use other libraries nor STL.

Basically it will be like this (I removed the variables from small list since they are irrelevant):
[image]

My structs are these:

```
struct small
{
    int data;
    struct small *next;
};


struct big
{
    int playerID;
    string playerName;
    string playerTeam;
    struct small *goals;
    struct big *next;
};
```

Here's the relevant code snippet, I think the problem is at addGoals(...) where I'm failing to assign the small element to the temp->goals.

```
class biglist
{
private:
    big *head, *tail;

public:
    biglist()
    {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }

. . .

void createbig(int ID, string name, string team)
    {
        big *temp = new big;
        temp->playerID = ID;
        temp->playerName = name;
        temp->playerTeam = team;
        temp->goals = NULL;
        temp->next = NULL;

        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = temp;
            tail = temp;
            temp = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = temp;
            tail = temp;
        }
    }

void addGoals(int id, small *s)
    {
        big *temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            if (temp->playerID == id)
            {
                temp->goals = s;
                break;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }

    void test()
{
    big *temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        if (temp->playerID == 1)
        {
            if (temp->goals !=NULL)
            {
                cout << temp->goals->data << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "goals null" << endl;
            }
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
}
. . .
```

```
class smalllist
{
private:
    small *head, *tail;

public:
    smalllist()
    {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }

    void createsmall(int ID, biglist b)
    {
        small *temp = new small;
        temp->data = ID;
        temp->next = NULL;

        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = temp;
            tail = temp;
            temp = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = temp;
            tail = temp;
        }


        b.addGoals(1, temp);
    }
};
```

Finally, my main code:

```
int main()
{
    biglist obj;
    obj.createbig(1, "Player1", "Team1");
    obj.createbig(2, "Player2", "Team2");
    obj.displaybig();

    smalllist sml;
    sml.createsmall(9, obj);
    sml.displaysmall();

    obj.displaybig();
    obj.test();
}
```

Debugging throws an exception at:

```
cout << temp->goals->data << endl;
```

saying that

> Exception thrown: read access violation. temp->goals was nullptr.

I'm 90% sure I messed up something with pointers; but other stuff I've tried gave errors before compiling. I checked out some books / tutorials but couldn't figure it out.

Also if you have a better approach or saw one of the horrible mistakes that I'm making, please don't hold back :)

Thanks.

---

**EDIT** I changed my `createbig()` like this.
Currently it works with following codes:

```
void createbig(int ID, string name, string team, small *s)
    {
        big *temp = new big;
        temp->playerID = ID;
        temp->playerName = name;
        temp->playerTeam = team;
        temp->goals = s;
        temp->next = NULL;

        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = temp;
            tail = temp;
            temp = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = temp;
            tail = temp;
        }
    }
```

and added this to small

```
small getsmall(int i)
    {
        small *temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            if (temp->data == i)
            {
                return *temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

My final main function is

```
int main()
{
    smalllist sml;
    sml.createsmall(9);
    sml.displaysmall();

    biglist obj;
    small s = sml.getsmall(9);
    obj.createbig(1, "Player1", "Team1", &s);
    //obj.createbig(2, "Player2", "Team2");
    obj.displaybig();

    obj.test();

}
```

While it ends successfully now, it gives the address of goals and I get this in debug section:

[image]

Comment: You have to check if this is a nullptr before dereferencing.

Comment: Does something call `addGoals()`?

Comment: In `addGoals()` you can break after `temp->goals = s;` no need to keep iterating if the id was already found.

Comment: @drescherjm I added the part where I call addGoals() and added your suggestion to addGoals().

Comment: Doesn't `b` go out of scope in `createsmall()`?

Comment: Where is the source for `createbig`? (Isn't that the call that is supposed to create the item in the big list that `test` is trying to output?)

Comment: Also, memory leaks each time this code says `new big` (outside `createbig` which was just added as I was typing).

Comment: I replaced them with `big *temp;`, was that what I should do? Still getting the same error by the way.

Comment: `big *temp = new big; temp = head;` is a bug in many functions. No need to allocate a new node if you are just using a pointer to some other node. just use `big *temp = head;` instead for this.

Comment: The following code in `createsmall()` does nothing useful: `biglist b; b.addGoals(1, temp);` the reason why I say that is after the `}` the variable `b` no longer exists. Maybe you thought this would  modify some other `biglist` object that you had previous created. I can tell you that it does not. `b` is a separate object that only exists in the scope of this function.

Comment: Yeah, added a nullptr check and you're right. How do I access to those "temp" elements out of createsmall() though

Comment: You need to somehow pass  the `biglist` that you are using to createsmall() preferably by reference. Without it createsmall() can not change `obj`

Comment: I think I did it, but still having the same error. I think I'll try to initialize each big list with a small list instead of declaring goals as null.

Comment: 0xcdcdcdcd is an uninitialized heap pointer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386/in-visual-studio-c-what-are-the-memory-allocation-representations

Comment: `temp->goals = &s;` is wrong. You can't take the address of a temporary and store that. when `s` goes out of scope  `temp->goals` points to garbage.

Comment: That usage is the same as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at what your code does, going through the `main` function. (Being able to walk through code like this is a useful skill. You can also use a debugger to help out, stepping through your function line-by-line.)

```
biglist obj;
```

Default construct a `biglist`. The `head` and `tail` are null. (By the way, `nullptr` is C++'s replacement for C's `NULL`.)

```
obj.createbig(1, "Player1", "Team1");
obj.createbig(2, "Player2", "Team2");
```

Add entries in `obj` for players with IDs 1 and 2. Their goals are null.

```
obj.displaybig();
```

Presumably an output of `obj`?

```
smalllist sml;
sml.createsmall(9);
sml.displaysmall();
```

These lines do something with a `smalllist`, but do not reference `obj`, so they are not relevant to this issue.

```
obj.displaybig();
```

Presumably an output of `obj`? Kind of redundant since nothing affected `obj` since the last display.

```
obj.test();
```

Call the test code, which finds the element for player ID 1 and outputs the data of that player's first goal. However, if you look up where that player was added, the goal is null, so you get a crash.

---

Separate from the above, there is probably some confusion in `createsmall`. Inside that function, a new `biglist` is created (not `obj`), and that list is told to add a goal to the player with ID 1. However, this has no effect the `biglist` in the main function.

Comment: Thanks forn the detailed reply.
Second `displaybig()` was to check if the results were same. Since I thought `addGoals()` called from `createsmall()` would change `obj`

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have added any goals, so I'm assuming the code initializes with null.
and so the nullptr exception.

call addgoals() with the goals to player before test().

the other suggestions would be

1. to add a null check before printing goals
2. temp pointers need not be initialized with new big or small just the head of the list would be enough

Comment: I updated with your suggestions.
`addGoals()` is called inside `createsmall()` though, so  it was called before `test()`

But apparently it doesn't do anything due to scope.